# Why won't my javascript open a new window?

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.open('timepop.php','window',width=400,height=200,left=0,top=100,screenX=0,screenY=100')</script>
```

When I put it into my browser as `javascript:window.open('timepop.php','window',width=400,height=200,left=0,top=100,screenX=0,screenY=100')` it works fine, but when placed into a live page, it doesnt.

Answer (score 4):

- `window` *might* not be a good name for a popup window, it might conflict with the global `window` object (not sure though)
- You are missing a quote in your third argument
- Check whether the window gets caught by a pop-up blocker.

Comment: The latter two nail it. In recent versions of web browsers, there is simply no way (in pure JavaScript) to open a window when the page is loaded without getting caught by the pop-up blocker.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing quote starting quote:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.open('timepop.php','window',width=400,height=200,left=0,top=100,screenX=0,screenY=100')</script>
                                                  ================^
```

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.open('timepop.php','window','width=400,height=200,left=0,top=100,screenX=0,screenY=100')</script>
```